After the installation is complete, the login page displays too many redirects and cannot be accessed
With the program is cloudlog, the address is: https://github.com/magicbug/Cloudlog，I didn't do any pseudo-static rules，Program installation after the completion of the default access address is: https://log.xxx.com/index.php/user/login; Accessing this will show that there are too many redirects，My nginx configuration file is as follows，:
 server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/log.xxx.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/log.xxx.com.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:;
  ssl_ciphers EC;
  ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites ;
  ssl_conf_command Options PrioritizeChaCha;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_buffer_size 2k;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  server_name log.xxx.com;
  access_log /data/wwwlogs/nginx.log combined;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  root /data/wwwroot/log;
  if ($ssl_protocol = "") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
  
  include /usr/local/nginx/conf/rewrite/other.conf;
  #error_page 404 /404.html;
  #error_page 502 /502.html;
  
  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
   # fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
  }
  

  location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|mp4|ico)$ {
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
    expires 7d;
    access_log off;
  }
  location ~ /(\.user\.ini|\.ht|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README\.md) {
    deny all;
  }
  location /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}

I hope you can give me some guidance on where the problem is and how to solve it
